# Transitioning, First Name Change

Tags: publications, career-path, minority

I have begun my transition (MtF) and my PhD. This includes, once I have jumped through all the legal hoops, changing my given name. I already have a publication, its very minor, but still I would like to reduce as many mentions as possible of my previous life, so to speak.
Can one contact Elsevier and ask them to change the name on a publication?
I also want to be as thorough as possible in changing my name, because historically trans rights are not a permament thing, so if the wind changes in 25 years I will hopefully still be alive and only a few ppl will know I am trans.

Comment: Note in particular the recently updated answer there which shows that Elsevier should be receptive.

Answer (score -1):

One can certainly contact Elsevier, explain the situation, and see what they say. However, generally any change to published work generates a paper trail, such as publication of an *Erratum* notice in the journal. This is likely to be contrary to your aims, as it would create a public link between your two identities.

Given that this apparently affects only one paper, the best option may be to quietly drop it from your publication list, so that there is no definitive evidence of a link to your new identity. Perhaps the author was your brother, or just a random stranger who happened to have the same surname.

Comment: This answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/195062/63475 indicates that Elsevier is part of a program that limits this paper trail for exactly the purpose OP is asking about https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/inclusive-author-name-changes